# CSVHelper headers wont get generated for nested collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, header, nested-lists, csvhelper

Trying to convert the list to CSV file, where I have nested collection.

Conversion works perfectly when CSV is read to object collection, but all headers are not generted back when the same collection is used to generate the CSV using the same mappings. Unable to figure what I am doing wrong, to generate all columns except the collection named columns like `Children, GrandChildren`.

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper.TypeConversion;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xunit;

namespace CSVHelperNugetHierarchyTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Parent> Parents;
        static List<string> Headers;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetCSV())))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) { HasHeaderRecord = true }))
                    {
                        csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<List<Child>>(new ChildrenConverter());
                        csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<List<GrandChild>>(new GrandChildrenConverter());
                        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ParentMapper>();
                        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ChildMapper>();
                        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<GrandChildMapper>();
                        Parents = csv.GetRecords<Parent>().ToList();
                        Headers = csv.HeaderRecord.ToList();
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) { HasHeaderRecord = true }))
                    {
                        csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<List<Child>>(new ChildrenConverter());
                        csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<List<GrandChild>>(new GrandChildrenConverter());
                        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ParentMapper>();
                        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ChildMapper>();
                        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<GrandChildMapper>();
                        csv.WriteRecords(Parents);
                    }
                }
                var streamBuffer = stream.ToArray();
                var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(streamBuffer);
                foreach (var item in Headers)
                {
                    Assert.Contains(item, content);
                }
            }
        }

        static string GetCSV()
        {
            return "Property0,Property1,Property2,Property3,Property4"
                + Environment.NewLine
                + "a,b,c,d,e";
        }
    }
    class Parent
    {
        public string Property0 { get; set; }
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }
    class Child
    {
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
        public List<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; }
    }
    class GrandChild
    {
        public string Property4 { get; set; }
    }
    class ParentMapper : ClassMap<Parent>
    {
        public ParentMapper()
        {
            Map(m => m.Property0);
            Map(m => m.Property1);
            Map(m => m.Children).Index(0);
        }
    }
    class ChildMapper : ClassMap<Child>
    {
        public ChildMapper()
        {
            Map(m => m.Property2);
            Map(m => m.Property3);
            Map(m => m.GrandChildren).Index(0);
        }
    }
    class GrandChildMapper : ClassMap<GrandChild>
    {
        public GrandChildMapper()
        {
            Map(m => m.Property4);
        }
    }
    class ChildrenConverter : ITypeConverter
    {
        public object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        {
            var children = new List<Child>();
            children.Add(row.GetRecord<Child>());
            return children;
        }

        public string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        {
            var children = value as List<Child>;
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                row.WriteRecord(child);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    class GrandChildrenConverter : ITypeConverter
    {
        public object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        {
            var children = new List<GrandChild>();
            children.Add(row.GetRecord<GrandChild>());
            return children;
        }

        public string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        {
            var children = value as List<GrandChild>;
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                row.WriteRecord(child);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Output received:

```
Property0,Children,Property1
a,c,e,d,b
```

Expected output:

```
Property0,Property1,Property2,Property3,Property4
a,b,c,d,e
```

I am using CsvHelper version `27.2.1`, in .NET Core 3.1 environment.

Have tried many things like, adding columns, indexes and column + indexes together.

PS: Have omitted few null checks and validations.

Comment: Are you only ever going to have 1 Child and 1 Grandchild?  And if so, why have `List<Child>` and `List<Grandchild>`?  If you have more than one of each Child and Grandchild, the complexity is going to increase.

Comment: Actually I will have semi-column `;` separated values in `Children` and `GrandChildren`. Which I am parsing in the converter, in my version.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have a `List<Child>` _and_ `List<Grandchild>` in a CSV file.  Have you tried to read it with `;` separated values? How are you going to know how many `GrandChildren` belong to the first `Child`.  Is it 1, 3, 100 `GrandChildren`?  If there is a solution, I think it will be to read each row manually and create your records.